# Does the relation aRb if (a+b) is not divisible by 4 has transitive property?

Tags: relations, programming

I recently encounter an programming problem in which I was to make subsets of set 'S' as following -
{ a + b should not be divisibe by 'k' where 'a' and 'b' are elements of S }

Of course I could just brute force through it and get an answer but I got interested in the fact that is this property transitive i.e. if a+b is not divisible by 'k' and if a+c is not divisible by 'k' then b+c is also not divisible by 'k'.
I could neither prove it not find an counter-example.

Extra question - this relation is definately not reflective, but would these subsets still make equivalance classes? why or why not?

Edit - thank you for your answers. Even though it seems like  a rather dumb question in hindsight, I appreciate your answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  No, here is a counterexample:  $1+2$ is not divisible by $4$ and $2+3$ isn't but $1+3$ is

Comment: Omg, how could I have been so oblivious that I didn't think of a simple example like this. or 5,6,7 even. I guess I was blind sighted by the set that was given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of reflexiveness already makes it not an equivalence relation, so they can't be equivalence classes. But note also that $1+2$ is not divisible by $4$, $2+3$ is not divisible by $4$, but $1+3$ is divisible by $4$, so transitivity fails as well.

Answer (score 1):

"Sum not divisible by $4$" is not an equivalence relation, because it is not reflexive nor transitive.  Here is a counterexample to transitivity:  $1+2$ is not divisible by $4$ and $2+3$ isn't but $1+3$ is.  Therefore this relation does not divide $S$ into equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0):

In general this relation is not transitive, but it depends on the set $S$.
There are trivial sets for which this is true, like

$S=\{1\}$ or $S=\{1,5\}$

Answer (score -1):

Counter-example :-

Let k = 4, a = 8, b = 6 and c = 10